# BigQuery JSON import internal error?

Tags: c#-4.0, google-bigquery

I am having a problem with JSON import to BigQuery. We have created service account and are using custom made .NET 4 library for all conversation between our server and BQ. Queries work, job listings work, basically all fetches work but uploading via JSON format does not work.

Here is what was returned with the job that was started:

```
{
 "kind": "bigquery#job",
 "etag": "\"WgwoVdnmFVq0E0riaWM5H0QXabs/R_b3J5b4GjwliMH_X8kjPNLVYsI\"",
 "id": "dot-metrics:job_f7eea1449bb24dffb0a0de1637f31abb",
 "selfLink": "https://www.googleapis.com/bigquery/v2/projects/dot-metrics/jobs/job_f7eea1449bb24dffb0a0de1637f31abb",
 "jobReference": {
  "projectId": "dot-metrics",
  "jobId": "job_f7eea1449bb24dffb0a0de1637f31abb"
 },
 "configuration": {
  "load": {
   "schema": {
    "fields": [
     {
      "name": "word",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
     },
     {
      "name": "word_count",
      "type": "INTEGER",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
     },
     {
      "name": "corpus",
      "type": "STRING",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
     },
     {
      "name": "corpus_date",
      "type": "INTEGER",
      "mode": "REQUIRED"
     }
    ]
   },
   "destinationTable": {
    "projectId": "dot-metrics",
    "datasetId": "DotMetric_TEST",
    "tableId": "TestTable"
   },
   "writeDisposition": "WRITE_APPEND",
   "allowQuotedNewlines": true,
   "sourceFormat": "NEWLINE_DELIMITED_JSON"
  }
 },
 "status": {
  "state": "DONE",
  "errorResult": {
   "reason": "internalError",
   "message": "Backend error. Job aborted."
  }
 },
 "statistics": {
  "startTime": "1350998303355",
  "endTime": "1350998337446",
  "load": {
   "inputFiles": "1",
   "inputFileBytes": "7359"
  }
 }
}
```

Data was JSON newline delimited string like this:

```
{"Word":"blah_139","WordCount":6615,"Corpus":"Corpus_678","CorpusDate": 6088201915056}
{"Word":"blah_602","WordCount":2978,"Corpus":"Corpus_493","CorpusDate": 6088201915056}
{"Word":"blah_50","WordCount":8315,"Corpus":"Corpus_360","CorpusDate": 6088201915056}
{"Word":"blah_736","WordCount":8971,"Corpus":"Corpus_751","CorpusDate": 6088201915056}
{"Word":"blah_243","WordCount":2362,"Corpus":"Corpus_174","CorpusDate": 6088201915056}
{"Word":"blah_643","WordCount":765,"Corpus":"Corpus_315","CorpusDate": 6088201915056}
```

Job is running for some time (about 10 seconds) but then just dies. Please HELP!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK it looks like you copied the shakespeare sample table and are appending to it. The shakespeare sample schema, because it was imported using a much older version of bigquery from source data that was internal to google, has  some warts on its schema. These warts cause your problem when we import to it (specifically, we think the corpus_date field should be an int32 field not an int64, even though bigquery only supports int32 for new data).

If you do a write_truncate instead of an append and pass a new schema, or do the import to an new table, you shouldn't have this problem.

Comment: I tried with `WRITE_TRUNCATE` and now the job has been `PENDING` for about 10minutes. Is this normal?

Comment: Good to know. If there are a lot of large imports going on, you can get stuck in pending for a while. Our worker pool should dynamically adjust when this happens, but sometimes it takes a few minutes to bring extra capacity online.